# Creating grandchild themes

Tags: magento2, theme, parent-child-theme

I'm using ultimo theme for a multi store configuration.
Since I have to update the theme regularly I don't want to make changes to the base files of it.But I've to make some changes which apply to all stores and severel specific changes within each store. Thats why I'm trying to create one child theme and a grandchild for every store. So I can make modifications for all stores within the child theme and modifications for specific stores within the grandchild themes.

I'm not sure if this is the usual way to do this but it seems to me most obvious and I havn't read that the theme inhgeritence is limited.

I've used the [official guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) to create the child themes. Unfortunatelly the changes made within allstores does not apply to my frontend which uses a grandchild theme. Maybe I made a misconfiguration, but I can't find it. 
When I apply the 'allstores' theme to my frontend I see the modifications, so I can assume that the 'allstores' child theme is well configured.

I've cleared the chache, re-indexed and forced to deplay after that.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

The theme.xml of the grandchild themes I set as follows:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
      <title>Store1</title>
      <parent>infortis/allstores</parent>
      <media>
          <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
      </media>
 </theme>
```

And the composer.json is configured like this:

```
{
    "name": "infortis/theme-frontend-store1",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|~7.1.0|~7.2.0",
        "infortis/theme-frontend-allstores": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "2.8.0",
    "license": [
        "Proprietary"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

This displays how my theme folder actually look like:

```
app/design/frontend/
├── infortis/
│   │   ├──base/  <-- core files
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├──ultimo/  <-- core files
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├──allstores/ <-- child theme
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├──store1/ <-- grandchild theme
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├──store2/ <-- grandchild theme
│   │   │   ├── ...
```

Do I miss somthing or arn't grandchild themes supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actual problem is in your theme.xml, Parent vendor name should be case sensitive

try the updated xml:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
      <title>Store1</title>
      <parent>Infortis/allstores</parent>
      <media>
          <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
      </media>
 </theme>
```

I hope it will helps.

Comment: Oh thanks, I was blind! Haven't seen this. But I recognized another issue. For each store I have several storeviews with different languages, I've added them to the deploy command which now is like this: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US en_GB fr_FR -f

Comment: glad to help, you can raise a new question with detail description what actually you got a problem in deploy, so that me or someone can help.